# How to run a query for multiple independent date ranges?

Tags: sql, datetime

I would like to run the below query that looks like this for week 1:

```
Select week(datetime), count(customer_call) from table where week(datetime) = 1 and week(orderdatetime) < 7
```

**... but for weeks 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 all in one query and with the 'week(orderdatetime)' to still be for the 6 weeks following the week(datetime) value.**

This means that for 'week(datetime) = 2', 'week(orderdatetime)' would be between 2 and 7 and so on.

'datetime' is a datetime field denoting registration.

'customer_call' is a datetime field denoting when they called.

'orderdatetime' is a datetime field denoting when they ordered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `group by`:

```
Select week(datetime), count(customer_call)
from table
where week(datetime) = 1 and week(orderdatetime) < 7
group by week(datetime);
```

I would also point out that `week` doesn't take the year into account, so you might want to include that in the `group by` or in a `where` filter.

EDIT:

If you want 6 weeks of cumulative counts, then use:

```
Select week(datetime), count(customer_call),
       sum(count(customer_call)) over (order by week(datetime)
                                       rows between 5 preceding and current row) as running_sum_6
from table
group by week(datetime);
```

Note:  If you want to filter this to particular weeks, then make this a subquery and filter in the outer query.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for your response - please could I follow up and ask how you might run this query but for weeks 2, 3, 4, 5 & 6 but in one query? Keeping the week(orderdatetime) as 6 weeks after the week(datetime) - so week(datetime) = 2, week(orderdatetime) between 2 and 7'.